# Query blocked by spid no 21 (SQL Server 2014)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

**Issue**: I am running this query that inserts about 3,300,000,000 rows from `table_A` into `table_B`:

```
declare @i bigint, @j bigint, @page int

set @i = 1
set @j = 110000000
set @page = 0

while @page < 33
begin
    insert into table_B
        select column1, column2
        from table_A
        where id between (@i + @j * @page) and (@j + @j * @page)

    set @page = @page + 1
end
```

The query has been running for about 3 days 17 hours, and it's still running. After I checked `sys.sysprocess`, I found this query (spid = 108) was blocked by another spid = 21. I try to use `dbcc inputbuffer (21)` to check what's spid = 21 doing, but I can't find anything about this spid = 21.

Querying sys.sysprocesses:

```
select *  
from sys.sysprocesses 
where blocked != 0
```

[image]

Running dbcc inputbuffer (21):

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: may be you need set database file size bigger before run script. read about FGCB_ADD_REMOVE here: https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/most-common-latch-classes-and-what-they-mean/

Comment: fun sp_WhoIsActive or sp_who2 if you don't want to download that script. Not sure why you put blocked != 0 in your query too. SPID 21 could also be blocked by another processes... sp_WhoIsActive allows you to display the entire blocking chain to see the *root* cause of your blocking. http://whoisactive.com/